# context.getExternalFilesDirs(null) doesn't return the SD card directory for Android 11 (API 30)

Tags: java, android, file, android-sdcard

My code

```
File[] contextDirs = context.getExternalFilesDirs(null);
```

When running in the emulator (Pixel 4 API 29) I get 2 directories

- 0 = {File@9770} "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mypackage/files"
- 1 = {File@9766} "/storage/11EC-1206/Android/data/com.mypackage/files"

When runing in the emulator (Nexus 4 API 30) I only get

- /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mypackage/files

On my *AndroidManifest.xml* I have *android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"* and I compile with *targetSdkVersion 29*

How can I have access to the files located in the SD card?

For info, the files are not media files and I am using *listFiles()* in some sub directories.

Comment: At defining an emulator you can choose for implementing an sd card. A Pixel device does not have the possiblility inserting an sd card. But the emulator can.

Comment: `How can I have access to the files located in the SD card` Wrong question. There is no sd card to begin with.

Comment: @blackapps for both emulation, I have Android Virtual Device Manager -> Virtual Device Configuration -> Show Advanced Settings -> SD card Studio Managed 512 MB

Comment: Starting from API level 30, you can not `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, please go through the official docs.

Comment: Can the Files app show the sd card?

Comment: Created an Nexus 4 API30 emulator and i do not have your problem. Maybe you could tryy to define a new emulator?

Comment: `On my AndroidManifest.xml I have android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" and I compile with targetSdkVersion 29` That all has nothing to do with it.

Comment: `please go through the official docs` @rahat Dont read the docs but try for yourself. All apps can create folders in most public directories like Documents, Download, DCIM, Pictures and so on and create files in those folders. Even on removable micro sd card.

Comment: @blackapps I created a new Nexus 4 API 30 with the same specs and now I have both directories. Thank you for you help!